# I can not make a very simple maven java web app run

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, web-applications

I have a very simple java web application where I use maven for build process and try deploying it on Tomcat.

I am using tomcat 7.0.5332, maven version 2.2.1.

Here is my very simple web app:

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.tugay.anotherwebapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>another-webapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>another-webapp Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax</groupId>
          <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
          <version>6.0</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>another-webapp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And here is my web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServletName</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServletName</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And MyServlet class:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * User: Tugay
 * Date: 4/5/14
 * Time: 9:14 PM
 */


public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                      HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

So

```
mvn clean install
```

works fine and the war is generated. But when deployed on Tomcat I get this:

```
- jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: /javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should set this dependency to provided:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>   
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Because it will already be in the tomcat shared classloader

Comment: Thanks, I will accept once I can. Time restirictions.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal. Servlet containers provide their own servlet-api implementation classes. So classes included in your war (from `javaee-api`) clash with ones provided by tomcat.

To avoid this, set the scope of the `javaee-api` dependency to `provided`.

This way classes provided by that dependency will be visible at compile time but the jar itself won't be included in the resulting war.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2 - you will find that the problem seems to be that you are trying to load Servlet class that is already provided by the container (Tomcat). Please, check whether servlet-api is in your war(it should not be) and use provided scope for javaee-api.

Comment: But in apache-tomcat-7.0.5332\lib folder I do not see any javaee-jar or anything similar?

Comment: There is servlet-api, is this the reason?

Comment: Yeah, that's the reason. Use provided scope for javaee-api and rebuild your war.